# Group rows of 2d array by one column and sum another column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I have an array:

```
Array 
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [setid] => 2
        [income] => 100
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [setid] => 2
        [income] => 120
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [setid] => 3
        [income] => 700
    )
)
```

I need to find entries with the same `setid`, sum their income up and delete duplicate entrys - in the end it should look like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [setid] => 2
        [income] => 220
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [setid] => 3
        [income] => 700
    )
)
```

Does someone know a sophisticated solution for my problem or do I have to take the long road and do every step manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a new array which you make fast adressable by using the setid as key. And reindex the array at the end.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $val) {
    if (!isset($result[$val['setid']]))
        $result[$val['setid']] = $val;
    else
        $result[$val['setid']]['income'] += $val['income'];
}
$result = array_values($result); // reindex array
```

Comment: (Alternatively you also could just use array_reduce, if you think this would be more elegant; but that here actually does the job too.)

Comment: @ bwoebi: much obliged! works like a charm - with a small alteration for my logic (negate if-clause):
`code`
if (!isset($result[$val['mitarbeiter_id']]))
`code`
otherwise it would not sum up the income.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$values = array();
foreach($array as $val) {
    if(isset($values[$val['setid']])) {
        $values[$val['setid']] += $val['income'];
    } else {
        $values[$val['setid']] = $val['income'];
    }
}
//all values are now in $values array, keys are setid and values are income
```

Comment: actually, you'd first need to create an array where the keys are setid…

Comment: I modified answer so you don't have to

Comment: Hehe, now it just nearly looks like my answer :-)

Comment: Yeah it would have worked the way before however it just throws a notice.

Comment: This doesn't create the desired structure.