# Eliminate Title but add qty if titles are identical in multidimensional array

Tags: php, magento

i have a multidimensional array that i:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title_0] => Sample Gift product 5
            [qty_0] => 1.0000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title_1] => Sample Gift product 2
            [qty_1] => 5.0000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title_2] => Sample Gift product 5
            [qty_2] => 1.0000
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title_3] => Sample Gift product 2
            [qty_3] => 1.0000
        )
)
```

But i want this result in such a way that if any title element has identical value in the array should deleted but their qty values must be added. Final array should look like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title_0] => Sample Gift product 5
            [qty_0] => 2.0000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title_1] => Sample Gift product 2
            [qty_1] => 6.0000
        )

)
```

Please help me i am stuck here have no idea how to deal with that. Thanks

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14958176/689579 or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19299261/689579

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new array that has `$arrayAll[$title] = $quantity;`
Loop your original array and if there is a key with title add quantity if not set initial quantity.

```
<?php
$aAll = array();

foreach ($multyArray as $i => $data) {
    $title = $data['title_'.$i];
    if( ! isset($aAll[$title] ) $aAll[$title] = 0;

    $aAll[$title] +=  $data['qty_'.$i];
}
// now you can recreate your original multy array with unique titles and added quantities.
```

Also you don't need to use `title_0` and `qty_0` , just use title and qty as they are unique keys for that array.