# combine the same values in array

Tags: php, arrays

Help me pls combine array values.
I have the same array:
In my case i should save customers name like a key.

```
    Array
(
    [Test Name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                   [name] => 
                  banana
                    [id] => 
                  45002
                    [quantity] => 
                  10
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 
                 banana
                    [id] => 
                 45002
                    [quantity] => 
                   20
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 
                    apple 
                    [id] => 
                   23402
                    [qua] => 
                    1
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 
                   cherry 
                    [id] => 
                   40017
                    [qua] => 
                   7
                )
```

How to get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [Test Name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                   [name] => 
                  banana
                    [id] => 
                  45002
                    [quantity] => 
                  30 // summ quantity but unique name and id 
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 
                    apple 
                    [id] => 
                   23402
                    [qua] => 
                    1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 
                   cherry 
                    [id] => 
                   40017
                    [qua] => 
                   7
                )
```

In my case i should save customers name like a key.
Then i will upload this on a table.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299166/php-array-find-duplicates-sum-them-up-delete-duplicates)

Comment: Hi. You need quantity & qua as different fields or same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_map` and `array_reduce` to accomplish it:

```
$results = array_map(function ($result) {
    return array_reduce($result, function ($carry, $item) {
        if (isset($carry[$item['id']])) {
            $carry[$item['id']]['quantity'] += $item['quantity'];
        } else {
            $carry[$item['id']] = $item;
        }
        return $carry;
    }, array());
}, $results);
```

From the documentation:

> **[array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)** returns an array containing all the elements of array1 after applying the callback function to each one.
>
> **[array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)** applies iteratively the callback function to the elements of the array, so as to reduce the array to a single value.

In our case the callback given to the `array_reduce` function returns a final array which contains unique items by `id`.