# PHP sum by other field from unique id in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an multidimensional array like this one:

```
Array
(
    [0] => array('id'=>1,'name'=>'Agent 1','total'=>3)
    [1] => array('id'=>2,'name'=>'Agent 2','total'=>3)
    [2] => array('id'=>3,'name'=>'Agent 3','total'=>3)
    [3] => array('id'=>1,'name'=>'Agent 1','total'=>6)
)
```

And I want to remove duplicate agents from this array and sum the `total` field to end up in a array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => array('id'=>1,'name'=>'Agent 1','total'=>9)
    [1] => array('id'=>2,'name'=>'Agent 2','total'=>3)
    [2] => array('id'=>3,'name'=>'Agent 3','total'=>3)
)
```

I have tried `array_unique` but it only remove duplicates...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php array find duplicates, sum them up & delete duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299166/php-array-find-duplicates-sum-them-up-delete-duplicates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code: [sandbox code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2c2219ec50cae2bb5014116ff0ec8fac27911463)
Main idea of algorithm - caching key pairs in result array and further checking existence of them.

```
$array = [
    0 => ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Agent 1', 'total' => 3],
    1 => ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Agent 2', 'total' => 3],
    2 => ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Agent 3', 'total' => 3],
    3 => ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Agent 1', 'total' => 6],
];

$sumArray = [];

foreach ($array as $agentInfo) {

    // create new item in result array if pair 'id'+'name' not exists
    if (!isset($sumArray[$agentInfo['id'].$agentInfo['name']])) {
        $sumArray[$agentInfo['id'].$agentInfo['name']] = $agentInfo;
    } else {
        // apply sum to existing element otherwise
        $sumArray[$agentInfo['id'].$agentInfo['name']]['total'] += $agentInfo['total'];
    }
}

// optional action to flush keys of array
$sumArray = array_values($sumArray);

print_r ($sumArray);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the exact output you desire, you will need a nested loop.

```
$input = array(
    0 => array('id'=>1,'name'=>'Agent 1','total'=>3),
    1 => array('id'=>2,'name'=>'Agent 2','total'=>3),
    2 => array('id'=>3,'name'=>'Agent 3','total'=>3),
    3 => array('id'=>1,'name'=>'Agent 1','total'=>6)
);
// This is where we will save our result
$output = array();

foreach ($input as $item) {
    // Used to determine if the current $item 
    // already exists in the $output array
    $foundItem = false;
    // Now we check the $item against every output entry
    foreach ($output as &$entry) {
        if ($entry["id"] == $item["id"]) {
            // Since we found a match, let's add the 
            //current item's total to the output total.
            $entry["total"] += $item["total"];
            // Marking this as true will later prevent us 
            // from inserting the item to the output array twice
            $foundItem = true;
        }
    }
    // If the item was not found in the output array
    // the $foundItem variable remains false
    // Using ! to negate the boolean, we insert the item to the output array
    if (!$foundItem) {
        $output[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Realize that this is not the only way to get the required output. This only is the simplest solution and can certainly be improved in many ways. However, I will leave that part up to you.

Answer (score 0):

assuming an id is unique you could use this

```
$array = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Agent 1', 'total' => 3),
    array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Agent 2', 'total' => 3),
    array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Agent 3', 'total' => 3),
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Agent 1', 'total' => 6)
);
$array_ids = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($array_ids[$value['id']])) {
        $array[$array_ids[$value['id']]]['total'] += $value['total'];
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
    else
    {
        $array_ids[$value['id']] = $key;
    }
}
```

in this way you save the used id's into array $array_ids, with that you can easily check if an agent already exists in the array

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) - Iteratively reduce the array to a single value using a callback function. And written a function according to the requirements. Hope this will help you.

```
<?php   
$array = [
    0 => ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Agent 1', 'total' => 3],
    1 => ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Agent 2', 'total' => 3],
    2 => ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Agent 3', 'total' => 3],
    3 => ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Agent 1', 'total' => 6],
    ];

$result = array_reduce($array, function($temp, $item){
    isset($temp[$item['id']])
       ? $temp[$item['id']]['total'] += $item['total']
       : $temp[$item['id']] = $item;
    return $temp;
}, []);

print_r($result);
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

> Array
>
> (
>
> [1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Agent 1 [total] => 9 )
>
> [2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Agent 2 [total] => 3 )
>
> [3] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Agent 3 [total] => 3 )
>
> )